# Understanding Decorator Design Pattern in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I just started to learn Decorator Design Pattern, unfortunately i had to go through various refrences to understand the Decorator pattern in a better manner which led me in great confusion. so, as far as my understanding is concern, i believe this is a decorator pattern

```
interface IComponent
{
    void Operation();
}
class Component : IComponent
{
    public void Operation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am walking ");
    }
}
class DecoratorA : IComponent
{
    IComponent component;
    public DecoratorA(IComponent c)
    {
        component = c;
    }
    public void Operation()
    {
        component.Operation();
        Console.WriteLine("in the rain");
    }
}
class DecoratorB : IComponent
{
    IComponent component;
    public DecoratorB(IComponent c)
    {
        component = c;
    }
    public void Operation()
    {
        component.Operation();
        Console.WriteLine("with an umbrella");
    }
}
class Client
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IComponent component = new Component();
        component.Operation();

        DecoratorA decoratorA = new DecoratorA(new Component());
        component.Operation();

        DecoratorB decoratorB = new DecoratorB(new Component());
        component.Operation();

        Console.Read();
    }
 }
```

But can the below code also be Decorator Pattern?

```
class Photo
{
    public void Draw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("draw a photo");
    }
}
class BorderedPhoto : Photo
{
    public void drawBorder()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("draw a border photo");
    }
}
class FramePhoto : BorderedPhoto
{
    public void frame()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("frame the photo");
    }
}
class Client
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Photo p = new Photo();
        p.Draw();

        BorderedPhoto b = new BorderedPhoto();
        b.Draw();
        b.drawBorder();

        FramePhoto f = new FramePhoto();
        f.Draw();
        f.drawBorder();
        f.frame();
    }
}
```

**My Understanding**

From the second example given by me, we can call all the three methods, but from the first example i wont be able to get access to all the three methods by creating a single object.

Comment: 1 - decorator, 2 - not. From my point, decorator should wrap decorated object :)

Comment: decorator is suppose to extend the methods, right!!!. then why the second one is not a Decorator Pattern? Could you help me understand?

Comment: @LijinJohn I would say it's because a decorator *decorates* an existing instance.  If I already have an instance of `Photo`, I can't simply decorate it by using `BorderedPhoto`, I'd have to create an instance of `BorderedPhoto` and then copy properties from my original `Photo` instance.  That's not decorating.

Comment: If you go here [https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns], read the "Criticism" section. Specifically, *Under ideal factoring, a concept should not be copied, but merely referenced. But if something is referenced instead of copied, then there is no "pattern" to label and catalog.*. . . .Lets say I have a class A. `class A { public A (B contained){} }`. . .and `A` may expose modified behavior of `B`. It is also decorator. No, not proxy. Proxy must create `class B` within itself by definition. So, my point is, the patterns you read about are classic implementations but feel free to interpret it.

Comment: @T.S. thank you very much for the explanantion :)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It should be a comment, but I have too many words.

For example, you have an object and interface, like `Repository : IRepository`.

```
public interface IRepository
{
    void SaveStuff();
}

public class Repository : IRepository
{
    public void SaveStuff()
    {
        // save stuff   
    }
}
```

and client, which probably was written by someone else

```
class RepoClient
{
    public void DoSomething(IRepository repo)
    {
        //...
        repo.SaveStuff();
    }
}
```

And once you decided, that ALL calls to repository should be logged. But you have a problem: the `Repository` class is from an external library and you don't want to change that code. So you need to extend the `Repository`'s behavior that you use. You write `RepositoryLogDecorator : IRepository`, and inside on each method do the logging, like

```
public class RepositoryLogDecorator  : IRepository
{
    public IRepository _inner;

    public RepositoryLogDecorator(IRepository inner)
    {
        _inner = inner;
    }

    public void SaveStuff()
    {
        // log enter to method
        try
        {
            _inner.SaveStuff();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // log exception
        }       
        // log exit to method
    }
}
```

So, before you could use client as

```
var client = new RepoClient();
client.DoSomething(new Repository());
```

but now you can use

```
var client = new RepoClient();
client.DoSomething(new RepositoryLogDecorator(new Repository()));
```

Note, that this is a very simple example. In real projects, where object created primary with DI container, you will be able to use decorator by changing some config.

So, decorator is used to extend functionality of object without changing object or client.

Another benefit of decorator: your decorator does not depend on `Repository` implementation. Only depends from an interface `IRepository`. Why this is an advantage? If somehow you decide to write you own implementation of `IRepository`

```
public class MyAwesomeRepository : IRepository
{
    public void SaveStuff()
    {
        // save stuff, but AWESOME!
    }
}
```

you will be able to automatically decorate this with decorator, which already exist

```
var client = new RepoClient();
client.DoSomethig(new RepositoryLogDecorator(new MyAwesomeRepository()));
```

Want to see example from real software? (just as sample, code is ugly, I know) => [go here](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/master/src/Arma3BE.Server/ServerDecorators/ThreadSafeBattleEyeServer.cs)

Comment: So its just a wrapper class then?

Comment: @JsonStatham [What are the differences between Decorator, Wrapper and Adapter patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40996203/312041)

Comment: @tym32167 Awsome answer. I have a question regarding to your specific example of a logging decorator. In cases unlike what you described, of using an external repository, would it be basically justified to make a decorator for logging purposes? from my pov, unless it's a specific case like you've described, it's an abuse, or misuse, of the decorator pattern.

Comment: @ilans its very depends of use case and way how you solve it. For example, if you want to have easy way to log any class of any method without implementing interfaces by yourself, yo can end up to AOP ( [one](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/february/aspect-oriented-programming-aspect-oriented-programming-with-the-realproxy-class), [two](https://doc.postsharp.net/add-logging#s3) ) which is all about generating decorators during compile/runtime. But if you want to introduce logging once in single small method, no point to create decorators, lust log what you need.

Answer (score 16):

There is this [PatternCraft series on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZt7mUVDijU&list=PL8B19C3040F6381A2) that explains Design Patterns with Starcraft, you should [check the video about Decorators here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=17XTOODeWQE).

In the video above the author gives an example with a `Marine` and `WeaponUpgrade`.

In the game you will have a `Marine` and then you can upgrade its weapon:

```
marine = new WeaponUpgrade(marine);
```

Note that you still have a marine there, it is not a new unit, it is the same unit with things that modifies its attributes.

```
public class MarineWeaponUpgrade : IMarine
{
    private IMarine marine;

    public MarineWeaponUpgrade(IMarine marine)
    {
        this.marine = marine;
    }

    public int Damage
    {
        get { return this.marine.Damage + 1; } // here
        set { this.marine.Damage = value; }
    }
}
```

You do that by creating a class that implements the same interface as your unit and access your unit properties to modify values.

There is a [Kata on CodeWars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5682e545fb263ecf7b000069) challenging you to complete the Weapon and Armor decorators for a marine.

Comment: thankyou for your youtube link, the videos were helpful :)

Answer (score 5):

Per [GOF page](http://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern%20GoF%20page) Decorator desing pattern:

> Attach additional responsibilities to an object dynamically. Decorators provide a flexible alternative to subclassing for extending functionality.

In your second example you are using inheritance to extend behaviour of a class, I believe this is technically not a Decorator design pattern.

Answer (score 4):

The decorator pattern allows you to add a specific behavior to an *individual object of a given type* without affecting other instances of that same type.

In your second example, which is normal inheritance, *all* instances of the class inherit the modified behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The second example is not a decorate pattern, since an essential ingredient to decorator pattern is that the object accepts one of its kind and possibly enhance it.

An instances of this in the first example is

`public DecoratorA(IComponent c)
 {
     component = c;
 }`

Also, the goal of the decorator pattern is to create "one" object, then decorate it by passing it through different filters or decorators.
Hence the line

`DecoratorA decoratorA = new DecoratorA(new Component());`

Should be

`DecoratorA decoratorA = new DecoratorA(component );`